# Can you see programmatically how much amperage a USB device is requesting in windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, usb

I don't necessarily need to see real time plots or anything but as I understand it if you attach a USB device it gets like 100 mA then after some negotiation it will bump the power up to 300 mA or 500 mA so on and so forth till the device stops requesting.

Does anyone know of anyway to see all the USB ports on a machine and what they are "allowed" to output?

edit update:

in windows 
preferably using a .net language

Comment: Voltage and current are different things.  I bet you'd like to see both...

Comment: @Paul: voltage is required to be 5. current is the only thing permitted to vary.

Comment: @John, well if you abuse the port, then either the voltage will drop from 5 or the port will shut off.  The real questions are what sensors are there, what do they measure, and can one easily get access...

Answer (score 5):

It must be available somewhere because if (in XP) you go to device manager and select one of the USB Root Hubs theer is a power tab in the properties dialog that details the power that has been requested by the devices plugged into each of the ports.

I am not a windows programmer so I do not know how to find this out programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark, but if this data is anywhere, it'll be in WMI, or you might be able to get the info from an ETW trace of usbhub/usbport.

Comment: I thought the same thing, so I browsed around using the WMI Object Browser so I could provide the asker with the WMI Class, but I could not find one.

Answer (score 0):

I found some interesting files under /sys but couldn't get anywhere with it.

In Ubuntu Linux, become root and cd to /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1

```
root@pjb-desktop:/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1# ls
1-0:1.0              bDeviceSubClass     configuration  idVendor      speed
authorized           bmAttributes        descriptors    manufacturer  subsystem
authorized_default   bMaxPacketSize0     dev            maxchild      uevent
bcdDevice            bMaxPower           devnum         power         urbnum
bConfigurationValue  bNumConfigurations  driver         product       version
bDeviceClass         bNumInterfaces      ep_00          quirks
bDeviceProtocol      busnum              idProduct      serial
root@pjb-desktop:/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1# cat bMaxPower 
  0mA
```

This seems to show current.

OK lets be a little creative here...

```
cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb?/bMaxPower0mA


 0mA
  0mA
  0mA
  0mA
  0mA
  0mA
  0mA
```

will list all of them.

I tried plugging in a USB stick and got it active so the LED was blinking.  I could not sense any change in these indications.  There is also a power directory but I found nothing in there I could decipher..

So sorry if this is a dead end but I think with a bit more looking you might find what you are after.

Comment: Question was changed to windows based after my answer.  I'll leave it up in case someone is interested.

Comment: I think that most USB interface chips don't provide that information.

Answer (score -1):

You could just attach a 5V )(or slightly higher voltage, i.e. 6 or 7) adapter w/ the highest current rating you have on hand (you'll likely be pressed to even find one over 750mA), but it's only going to draw depending on the demand the attached devices require. In order to determine 'how much' or the ideal adapter, put a meter in the circuit and put your devices in their highest power requirement mode and read your meter (set on DC Amps)

Comment: He's looking for a programming answer